# java 7 try-with-resource syntax error

Tags: eclipse, java-7, try-with-resources

I'm getting "Syntax error on token "(", { expected" on the try(BufferReader.. line in Eclipse when I try to use the new Java 7 try-with-resource.(code snippet below) This is directly copied from the java nio tutorial http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

I have the build path configured to latest java7 location and I know it's configured properly as I'm using other java.nio features like Path and SimpleFileVistor without any problems. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

```
        try(BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file, charset)) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            }
        }catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.format("IOException in reading " + file.getFileName().toString()+ x);
        }

        return testCaseNames;
```

Answer (score 4):

Please check the compiler compliance level in project properties, it should say 1.7. Also which version of Eclipse are you using ? The support in present only in recent builds - see http://thecoderlounge.blogspot.com/2011/07/java-7-support-in-eclipse-371-38-42.html

Answer (score 2):

`Path` and `SimpleFileVisitor` are library classes and don't require any specific editor support for the new syntax.

In Eclipse it's not the JDK that's compiling the classes, but Eclipse's own compiler `JDT`. This is the one that should support the new syntax and is only available in the most recent builds of Eclipse 3.7 and not in any official version that you can download from the normal download page.